# How to fire validation error for input field from child component to parent component in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have 2 lwc components compA and compB. CompA is the parent component consisting of next button where as compB is my child component having input text field. If my input text field(child component's field) is empty; on click of next button (parent component's button) a validation error like 'Your input field is empty' should pop-up. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It will be better if you provide the code snippets for this

Comment: Please use code snippet it will help us understand. Please check the component library see if "required" attribute works for you. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification 
and this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create @api method to validate child components text input field. Here you can use template.queryselector to access the value of the text field.
onclick of next button call the api method of child component